If a proton starts at an infinite distance from another positively charged particle, could it be said that the distance will always be infinite?
I understand the solution with calculating the distance the proton would be able to close maximally to the particle, but physically it would be impossible to change the distance from infinity to anything else, right?

I'm going to change your example from two protons to a proton and an electron, since then the particles attract instead of repel, which I think is easier to think about.
If the two particles start off separated by a distance $d$, then the two particles will attract each other, and eventually meet, after a time $t$ that grows with $d$ (it's a fun exercise to work out how $t$ depends on $d$! -- at least, assuming that we can use electrostatics to describe the entire process). When they are far apart (large $d$), the particles spend a long time with a very large separation where the attractive force between them is very small and therefore they do not accelerate very much. In the limit that $d\rightarrow \infty$, it is true that $t\rightarrow \infty$.
However, we usually don't ever say that some physical quantity is literally equal to infinity. Physically, this is not very meaningful. How can you arrange an experiment where two particles are infinitely far apart? Mathematically, you run into paradoxes if you try to treat infinity like an ordinary real number. For instance, if you try to say $1/0=\infty$, then multiplying both sides by $2$ you get $2/0=\infty$, and then you could conclude that $1=2$. Therefore it is necessary to deal with infinity more carefully, which in physics usually involves talking about a limit of a finite process where some parameter becomes arbitrarily large (in this example, $d\rightarrow \infty$).
So I would answer the question in your title as "it doesn't make sense for two particles to be an infinite distance apart, but in the limit where the initial distance between them becomes arbitrarily large and the particles are initially at rest with respect to each other, the force on each one becomes arbitrarily small, meaning that the time it takes for the distance between them to change by a set amount grows without bound."

+1, but a comment about your 1/0 example: saying that 1/0 should equal 2/0 is an everyday aspect of projective geometry, where it causes no problems. The problem is concluding that you can cancel the "/0"s to get 1 = 2. Many of the problems with division by zero are really problems with dividing zero by itself.

@RobinSaunders Thanks! It makes sense that you could use projective geometry to make sesne of those expressions. My goal certainly wasn't to be mathematically rigorous and cover all possible interpretations, I just wanted to give a commonly used example of where "treating infinity as a standard cardinal number" leads to contradictions.

TLDR:
It is pointless to think what is happening in infinity. Infinity was introduced to analyse what's happening while approaching it.

Infinity is tricky. Very tricky, and beautiful in it's own way. And it's not Real. It is more "what would happen if we go a bit further".
You know about rational numbers and real numbers. If you try infinitisimaly small difference between two real numbers, you can squeeze one more in between them. Actually, you can squeeze rational number in between any two real numbers. More interstingly, you can squeeze irrational number between any pair of rational numbers and vice versa.
Let's set function $f(x): R\rightarrow R$ this way: $$x\in Q: f(x)=1, x\notin Q$$
Is this function alternating? We can't say!
That's the spirit of infinity. In math, you cannot treat it as real number. In physics you cannot reach it, you can only approach it.
Physics tries to describe what's going on and how. This way it's based on hypotheses and experiments. If the hypothetical prediction matches the experiment, we're happy, the hypothesy was proven.
Problem is, we have to allways simplify things. We need to neglect something. And we cannot measure anything precisely, there is allways some uncertainity and some error.
Luckily, we don't need to care most of the time. We need to keep within limits, and things are fine. We can build bridges, use computers etc.
The infinity helps here a lot. You can translate it as "number large enough it gets out of our frame and something we neglected will fail beforehand."
Your example with two charges is a good one here. Let's go other way, proton and electron infinitisimaly close. The force of attraction is infinite! Luckily we cannot use Faraday's law but we need to dive in quantum mechanics.
If you place something somewhere, it gets real coordinates and its in real distance form something else. Trick is, give me any real number and I'll give you different real number, but bigger. So when you place something real in "infinity" it gets real and I can put something else even farther.
Simillarly when the distances are extremely high there is something we neglected on smaller scale that renders the two particles independent.
For damped oscillator, out teacher jokingly answered "t reaches infinity in about 5 minutes."
In calculus we were jokingly saying "f(x) goes to infinity" instead of "f(x) diverges to infinity" and "f(x) goes to bigger infinity than g(x)" instead of "f(x) diverges to infinity faster than g(x) does".
